# How to remove ANSI escape character in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to export the console output from Linux machine after running sh command through UiPath using C# nuget package.

When I write it into notepad I am getting below

```
]0;sqsuser@primedbdmc:~[sqsuser@primedbdmc ~]$
```

The same is coming like below when i store the value in a runtime variable

```
\u001b]0;sqsuser@primedbdmc:~\a\u001b[?1034h[sqsuser@primedbdmc ~]$
```

I would like to remove this using code or regex in UiPath but I couldnt done via regex. Please help

Comment: Why couldn't you? What was the issue? Why regex, if it is a fixed text?

Comment: The return character for windows and c# are different.  Windows user "\n" (0x0C, 0x0A) while linux uses "\r" (0x0A).  So easiest fix is to make sure in Linux you terminate each line with the windows return characters.

Comment: @jdweng We are doing this for our RPA development and the commands are running in UiPath. The results / output are written into notepad programmatically so either I need to use regex or cover in C#. So please advise the suitable regex to remove as I tried multiple combination but its not working

Comment: Exactly what do you want to remove? Just the escape characters or the whole prompt? The prompt seems to end in a $, so search for that?

Comment: You have a GRAMMAR/LANGUAGE that you are attempting to parse.  It probably not as simple as removing escape characters.  Your parsing has to have rules which is not going to be a single Regex.  You are going to need something like a compiler.  Do a web search for YACC which is a tool developed by Bell Labs to parse languages.  It used Lex (which is similar to Regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, the solution is below

```
Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(str_Response,""\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])"",""),"\a","")
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
    var s = <Dirty String>
    new Regex(@"\x1B\[[^@-~]*[@-~]").Replace(s, "");
```